# go build, cannot find module for path

Tags: go

I get a golang project form github, I have inited go mod and modified relative import. but when execute `go build main.go`,  error as follow:

```sh
build _/D_/myCode/jd_seckill-1/common: cannot find module for path _/D_/myCode/jd_seckill-1/common
```

This is go.mod that created after I executed `go mod init jdSeckill`

```golang
module jdSeckill

go 1.13

require (
    github.com/Albert-Zhan/httpc v0.0.0-20210208112951-8d16c3e27c04
    github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery v1.6.1
    github.com/tidwall/gjson v1.6.8
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.5
)
```

This is main.go have be modified by me

```
package main

import (
    "jdSeckill/common"    //   ../common   before modified
    "jdSeckill/conf"      //   ../conf     before modified
    "jdSeckill/jd_seckill"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Albert-Zhan/httpc"
    "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)
```

The common code as follow picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSGj4.jpg)

Comment: Did the go path is the same directory as this project ? If in that case move your module project to other dir.

Comment: The directory of the project is not  same with go path

Comment: what is the version of go used?

Comment: go version go1.13.11 windows/amd64

Comment: Maybe not the solution to your problem but nevertheless wort starting with it: Go 1.13 is outdated, use 1.16. Do not use filename arguments on `go build`. Building Go code is done by running `go build` with _no_ arguments. Show source code layout: is go.main at the root? Where is common, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Go's module functionality was designed for the public external modules. If you want to use local modules, you should use "replace" directive of go mod

See here - https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Here is the example of the go mod replace:

```
module github.com/user/service

replace github.com/user/depservice => /Users/user/Projects/depservice

require (
    github.com/user/depservice v1.1.1
)
```